# Problems with mapping and types in haskell higher order functions

Tags: haskell

I have a higher order function as follows. F1 is simply adding 1 to the first element, but I want it to map to all elements and the second is getting a type error. I am wondering how I fix these problems.
'''

```
hof :: a -> (a->a->a) -> [a] -> a
hof x _ [] = x
hof x f (y:ys) = f y (hof x f ys)


f1 :: (Num a)=> [a] -> a
f1 xs = hof 0 g xs  
      where g a b = 1 + a

f2 :: [a] -> [a]
f2 (x:xs) = hof [] (++) (x:xs)
```

expected behavior should be

```
f1 [] = 0
f1 x:xs = 1 + f1 xs

f2 [] = []
f2 (x:xs) = x ++ f4 xs
```

Comment: Your `hof` essentially takes a `[a]` and produces an `a`. You can't use that, unchanged, and turn a `[a]` into an `[a]`. This could be possible if `hof` had the type of `foldr`, which is more general since the result does not have to be `a`.

Comment: I'm not able to check this at the moment, but it's very helpful if you include the full error message in your question. PS your `hof` is just a restricted form of `foldr`, with the arguments in a different order - this function is used everywhere in Haskell so I would advise getting familiar with it rather than rolling your own version.

Answer (score 0):

`g` in the first version of `f1` doesn’t use `b`. In your definition of `hof` that argument is where the recursion happens. If you don’t use that argument you won’t iterate over the list.

As for the type error for `f2`: look closely at the type of `(++)`, the function required by `hof` and the type you’ve said `f2` should have. I suspect that if you remove your type signature what you have will compile. Then you could use GHCi to ask for the inferred type for `f2`.

It might be a good idea to remove the pattern matching from `f2` before you go to test it.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Removing the type signature from f2 gives the following error. *Main> f2 [1,2,3] [1,2,3]

<interactive>:22:1: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Integer] -> t'
                  with actual type `[a0]'
    * The function `f2' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `[[a0]] -> [a0]' has only one
      In the expression: f2 [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
      In an equation for `it': it = f2 [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
    * Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:22:1)

Comment: That’s not a bad type error we’re not always so lucky with GHC :D. 

First, `f2` expects one list, not two. Second, the inferred type of `f2` is there in the error message: `[[a0]] -> [a0]`